# Angular: How can I extract one attribute from API call response?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, request, jwt

I've got a Django Rest Framework backend and a Angular frontend.
I use JWT for authentication. When I try to get a token I get the following result as JSON:

```
{
    "refresh": "jfksdajfkjsdkafjasdjfkjsdkfjksdfjfj8j2qfj2jjf",
    "access": "asjdfijajf8wjfw8ijf89wfj08jfw890ijf8wsf098wsfjaw"
}
```

My code looks like this:
**Auth Service**

```
private token: Observable<string>;

private params = {
    params: new HttpParams()
      .set('username', 'MYUSERNAME')
      .set('password', 'MYPASSWORD')
      .set('content-type', 'application/json')
  };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getToken(): Observable<any>{
    this.token = this.http.post('https://www.mywebsite.com/api-token', this.params);
    return this.token;
  }
```

**Application**

```
private url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/movies';

private data = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`,
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthServiceService) { }

fetchMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
  console.log(this.data);
  return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.url, this.data);
}
```

When I try to run this code i get a "bad_authorization_header"
Detail: "Authorization header must contain two space-delimited values"

I think the error occours because I pass the refresh and the access token together.
How can I extract the access token only?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to subscribe it. But you may also have async problem if you set bearer like that in application. I suggest you to set to session while login and set to session there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change getToken To :-

```
getToken(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post('https://www.mywebsite.com/api-token', this.params).pipe(map((res)=>res.access));
  }
```

change data like :-

```
this.authService.getToken().subscribe((token)=>{
   this.data = = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    })
});
```

Comment: When I try to add the "res.access) i get the following error: Property 'access' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: try printing res, what does it give to you?